# Asp.net Core 2.0 Static files not found error

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create an ASP.net Core 2.0 web application; I have placed the static files in a folder called Content.

[image]

I am giving the following path:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("../Content/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am getting a 404 - not found error when loading the view. However the GET request path is correct and the file exists in the same path. This is the path to which the GET request is being done:

```
http://localhost:49933/Content/css/style.css
```

I found solutions that requires me to change settings in web.config file, But .Net Core 2.0 does not have one. I have used MVC. Isn't web.config file very important for IIS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should place the static files you wish to expose under `wwwroot` and then reference them accordingly e.g.

See [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

If you want to serve static files outside of the `wwwroot` then you will need to configure static file middleware as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
        RequestPath = "/Content"
    });
}
```

You can then use similar markup to what you have currently:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

See [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) for more information.